# How to record mutation and action in "vue js dev tools" beta version?

Tags: vuex, vuejs3, mutation, vue-devtools

I'm working on vue3 and managing state using Vuex, but I'm not able to load mutation and actions in the vuejs devtools beta version. Also no recording feature.
[Image of my vuejs Devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eaWE.png)

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you find the solution?

Comment: No I didn't find its solution from any forum

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

Updated Vue DevTool chrome extension released couple of hours back with support for tracking mutations / actions!!

---

Looks like Vue Devtool beta for Vue 3 doesn't support recording actions / mutations yet.

The best alternative I have found is to use `createLogger()` plugin, which will then log all actions and mutations to the console.

```
import { createStore, createLogger } from "vuex";
export default createStore({
    state: {},
    mutations: {},
    actions: {},
    modules: {},
    plugins: [createLogger()]
});
```

Chrome Devtools window
[image: Chrome Devtools window]

Answer (score 0):

Just go to "Timeline"

[image]

Comment: No longer works see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71856161/where-has-vue-devtoolss-time-travel-debugging-feature-gone